# How to debug a framework in OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, frameworks, sdl-2

SDL2 framework causes a crash in my application. I would like to debug the framework code (i.e. place a breakpoint in a file inside the framework) to examine the problem further. How can I do this?

I have the SDL2 framework project with the source code. I can build both projects with debugging information etc.

I tried to attach (Debug > Attach to Process... > APPNAME) the SDL2 project to the running instance of my app, but I receive the following error:

```
Lost connection to "My Mac". Restore the connection to "My Mac" and
run APPNAME again, or if APPNAME is still running, you can attach to
it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > APPNAME.
```

If debugging a framework is impossible, I'd like to know the best way to debug a third-party library in OS X. The SDL2 project gives option to build the library as a static or dynamic library as well.

Comment: There are many reports of this with XCode 6.1/6.2 though they seem to deal primarily with iPad/iPhone/iSimulator connections.  I'm also getting it, however, trying to attach to an external app I've built outside of XCode.  The suggestions are always to just re-run the app from the beginning but that doesn't help me.  We may have to wait for a new release of XCode that fixes this.